# Looking for a Frontpage alternative (web design IDE)

Tags: software-recommendation, web-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)

Is there any Frontpage alternatives out there I can use?

***Please list any and all alternatives available with a recommendation per answer.***

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is `BlueGriffon` 
[image]

> Is an open source, cross-platform WYSIWYG editor has reached version 1.0. You can use it to >edit / design web pages and supports CSS3 and HTML5, web forms, web fonts and more.

[BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/)

Comment: shame on you for using a osx screenie :P

Comment: Haha, well That is just a picture, I don't use osx :D

Answer (score 3):

## [KompoZer](http://kompozer.net/) ( [Click To Install](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/kompozer) )

[image]

> KompoZer is a complete web authoring system that combines web file management and easy-to-use WYSIWYG web page editing.
>
> KompoZer is designed to be extremely easy to use, making it ideal for non-technical computer users who want to create an attractive, professional-looking web site without needing to know HTML or web coding.

Comment: I'm going with BlueGriffon since it's based on Firefox engine and forgoes K libraries.

Comment: @Oxwivi this is also based on firefox engine and it does not depend on kde libraries and anyways this kde libraries talk is all crap they take only space and that is less than a 100 mb which is nothing on todays hdds and they can be integrated into the system as well .

Answer (score 1):

There is `Bluefish Editor`: [Click to install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/bluefish)

[image]

> Even though Bluefish is not a WYSIWYG editor - it is still considered a strong tool.
>   It is a GTK+ HTML editor for the experienced web designer. Its features include nice wizards for startup, tables and frames; a fully featured image insert dialog; thumbnail creation and automatically linking of the thumbnail with the original image; and configurable HTML syntax highlighting.

[Bluefish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Go text-mode:

http://www.w3schools.com/

and preview/debug/tune your work with FireBug firefox plugin:

http://getfirebug.com/