# Easily make website without coding

Tags: software-recommendation, websites, web-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)

I know Windows has some create programs to make websites attractive websites without coding.  Can anyone recommend to me some programs that run on Linux where I can create my own websites with a  fair amount of flexibility in design?

Answer (score 4):

Well, firstly I would whole-heartedly recommend you to either learn HTML/CSS/JavaScript or install one of the million of Content Management Systems (CMS) available, most of which would allow you to install themes or somehow else customize their look. You would even be able to build a custom theme though it would most likely require learning something about the above mentioned technologies.

Building websites in FrontPage-like programs is sooo like year 1998 :)

Secondly, there are some WYSIWYG HTML editors available, for example

- [Blue Griffon](http://bluegriffon.org/) (seems to be the most actively maintained)
- [Kompozer](http://www.kompozer.net/)

[image: Kompozer screenshot]

- [Quanta Plus](http://quanta.kdewebdev.org/) (haven't been ported to KDE4, site is down)
- [Amaya](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/)

[image: Amaya screenshot]

Comment: @mateo_salta: Quanta Plus has been abandoned as far as I know. I added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a program, per se, but if you have a Google account you could always use [Google Sites](https://sites.google.com/) to easily create a website in your browser and for free, with pretty much no coding necessary (though you can still tweak some of the HTML yourself later if you feel like it). Probably the best part of this is that since your site will be hosted by Google and the tools run in your browser, you can use it to work on your site(s) on any computer with Internet access. In fact, this is what I'm using right now for a hobby project of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [Bluegriffon](http://bluegriffon.org).  It has good support for `HTML5` and `CSS3`. About Bluegriffon, from its website:

> BlueGriffon is a new WYSIWYG content editor for the World Wide Web.
>   Powered by Gecko, the rendering engine of Firefox, it's a modern and
>   robust solution to edit Web pages in conformance to the latest Web
>   Standards.

I have detailed its installation at: https://askubuntu.com/a/204698/11932

This is what it looks like:
[image: Bluegriffon Window]