# For a newbie, what software/ IDE is best to build a website?

Tags: software-recommendation, websites, html, web-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)

What software would you recommend for a newbie (not much experience in HTML code) to develop websites? It would be great if it is simple to use (for basic work) but can also support advanced usage.

Will it be better to go for an IDE or a standalone editor kind of program?

The website will have basic stuff like Drop-Down-On-Hover menus, buttons, Change-Color-On-Hover buttons, images and text in multiple columns, etc.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/64619/18612) help you at all?

Comment: You have several graphical tools that can get you started, but nothing replaces learning to code. I suggest you take a look at bluefish. Tools such as kompozer are "OK" for starting, but they write long sloppy code and at some point you will almost certainly need to debug it.

Comment: Best way: take an editor (gedit) and learn html yourself. You do not need an IDE for that! And you will learn coding from the beginning, you will understand what you re doing. Look at selfhtml.org if you understand german or french this is the best choice for you.

Comment: Are you looking for an [alternative to Dreamweaver](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Regarding Drop-Down-On-Hover menus, buttons, Change-Color-On-Hover buttons, images and text in multiple columns,

You may find  `Web Developer Tools` very helpful.  You may download the .deb file here -> [WDT](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=129726)

[image]

You can find many menus source code from many websites inside WDT

[image]

You may generate css Menus

[image]

Image processing tools

[image]

HTML editor

[image]

Please check also the following questions they have great and helpful answers.  You may find many helpful tools from them.

- [Easily make website without coding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64619/easily-make-website-without-coding)
- [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)
- [CSS editor with real-time preview and selector localization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59474/css-editor-with-real-time-preview-and-selector-localization)
- [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)
- [What IDEs are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu)

Comment: + 1 great answer

Comment: Very very useful. Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned several WYSIGYG (what you see is what you get) editors. However, they're quite limited. If simplicity is what you're after, I recommend something like [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com). But really, you should learn HTML and CSS. They aren't too difficult, and they'll open up many possibilities. In my opinion, except for quickly-thrown-together sites, you want to write the site yourself.

Suggested editors: Everyone has their own favorites. I mostly use Gedit and VIM. Others have other preferences. No matter. Any decent editor will have HTML support built in.