# Web Development in Ubuntu

Tags: webserver, ide, websites, html, web-development

I cannot seem to find info on creating web pages on my Ubuntu 12.10 server.
Is there a program to do this like Microsoft has (such as Frontpage)?

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10, PHPMyadmin, MYSql, Lamp server, postfix.

Now what should I do?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/48299/44179

Comment: @iSeth I don't know if MikeM24 wants an IDEs, so this may not be a duplicate.

Comment: @Vreality Right.  That's why its "Possible" duplicate ;)

Comment: Front page is discontinued and replaced by visual web developer. If you want similar app for ubuntu  try bluegriffon

Comment: In case the OP wants a WYSIWYG HTML editor, this question is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/64619/easily-make-website-without-coding/64628#64628  Otherwise it's a duplicate of the question about IDEs linked to @iSeth

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)

Answer (score 2):

Usually servers are set to hold and serve pages, the development machine is at the hand of the developer, and syncs the web application using a protocol such as SFTP, FTP or WebDav.

If you have a xserver desktop on your machine, I'd recommend you Gedit that can be set up to be a great text editor for web development. (Some tips [here](http://lifehacker.com/321945/give-gedit-the-power-of-textmate))

For non-GUI use (i.e. ssh access) there is vim which is widely used, and nano which is very simple.

Comment: There is another way to improve Gedit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387432/how-to-make-gedit-look-like-textmate

Answer (score 0):

Vim is a great start. If you plan on making it yourself, a text editor like vim or an IDE such as geany would probably suit you well.
If you're learning, making it yourself is the best way in my opinion.

[Here](http://tips.webdesign10.com/using-linux-for-web-design-and-development-ubuntu) are some editors to look into.
If you want a "What You See Is What You Get" kind of editor (like Dreamweaver) then [Kompozer](http://www.kompozer.net/) looks like a good option if you don't mind compiling from source.
[Amaya](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/) and [SeaMonkey](http://www.seamonkey-project.org/) are two other options.
Here's a paid app you could check out: [quickandeasywebbuilder](http://www.quickandeasywebbuilder.com/)

Comment: Kompozer is no longer maintained so it is not available in ubuntu 12.10 repository. Blue griffon is better than kompozer