# I need an Open source Dreamweaver alternative

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, software-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)

am using ubuntu and i need an Open source Dreamweaver alternatives

i hope to fide software that help me to do my work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

For quick and effortless web development - Quanta Plus is steadily becoming a worthwhile competitor to the commercial web editors on the market. Quanta Plus's features include multi-document interface, WYSIWYG editing and templates. Among the advanced features your will find team development, plug-in support and a PHP debugger. The objective of the team behind Quanta Plus is simply to developer the best tool for web development.

Comment: Thanx , and is there any software more Pro and Advanced ?