# Web design software

Tags: software-recommendation, web-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)

what software do you use, or you recommend me using for designing web pages? I don't mean WYSIWYG software, but more like adobe photoshop. I'm aware of gimp, but i don't like the separate windows thingie ... I looked into inkscape and it seems promising but cant find any good tutorials(for webdesign).

So what's your opinion on this topic?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This site is intended for questions that can be answered directly; discussions or questions pertaining to opinions are beyond its scope. Take a look at the [kind of questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask) that are welcome here, and check out the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/), where you may find more appropriate feedback for your question.

Comment: I don't get the question. What are you looking for? Software to make websites (like bluefish, emacs, vi, gedit,...) or a photo editing tool (adobe photoshop, gimp,...) or a vector graphics tool (inkscape, xfig, adobe illustrator,...)?

Comment: not WYSIWYG but more like photoshop? Photoshop is WYSIWYG...

Answer (score 3):

I use Netbeans IDE as the Php Editor. Because of It's built-in php-manual and variable, function assist. It also provides suggestions (can be closed) for like "alt" attribute of "img" in html.

It can also be used as FTP engine to upload project to server.

---

Gimp is really good. But if you trying to compare Gimp with Inkscape; that is not a good idea.

Gimp is a photo editor, and is pixel based. Inscape is vector based, and used to create logos etc, which are resizable. (Sure using both in one project, not selecting one)

Both are really useful and enough to create a professional looking web applications.

By the way, you can try learning Illustrator and doing the same for inkscape.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse is better one, it's support (HTML - CSS - PHP - Javascript), that's mean all you need to code your pages (eclipse helios). here to download it:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/sr2

For Design i recommend you to use gimp it's a good if you have knowledge in photoshop

Answer (score 2):

Please check out [Bluegriffon](http://bluegriffon.org).  It has good support for `HTML5` and `CSS3`. About Bluegriffon, from its website:

> BlueGriffon is a new WYSIWYG content editor for the World Wide Web.
>   Powered by Gecko, the rendering engine of Firefox, it's a modern and
>   robust solution to edit Web pages in conformance to the latest Web
>   Standards.

I have detailed its installation at: https://askubuntu.com/a/204698/11932

This is what it looks like:
[image: Bluegriffon Window]

Comment: Athu html5 support cheyyumo?

Comment: @Tachyons, Sure. It has good support for HTML5 and CSS3. Just check its [official site](http://bluegriffon.org/). They have various tabs for each of these(I can't link to those).

Comment: @Tachyons, Updated my answer with that info.

Answer (score 1):

Bluefish Web Editor is a nice choice . [Download it here](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

try [kompozer](http://kompozer.net/) it is a good tool for web designing it is easy to use. it is available on ubuntu software center search for it and install it. it is free and open source.
another option is if you want to create only web pages:
libre office writer it is very powerful and you can export your page to html pdf and other formats. libre ofice wirtter comes pr installed try them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the separate window thing either and lucky for us Gimp just added another feature where you can put all the windows into one, similar to Photoshop's style.

Go to your menu bar at "windows -> Single-Window Mode"

Hope this helps.