# Kompozer not in the repo?

Tags: ide, web-design

Why is Kompozer no longer in the repositories? Can any one suggest a new alternative (other than BlueFish) ?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/204704/where-do-i-look-for-the-reason-for-removing-a-package-from-the-ubuntu-repositori

Comment: @A.S. I had asked that question just to know the reason for it. :)

Comment: I searched before asking but found no thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Kompozer` was removed from the repository as it is no longer being maintained by its maintainer in the upstream(`Debian`).
**References:**

- http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=690251
- http://packages.qa.debian.org/k/kompozer.html

As for your second question,
a suitable alternative for it would be [Bluegriffon](http://bluegriffon.org).

This is what it looks like:
[image: Bluegriffon Window]

To install it do the following steps:

1. Download the [installer](http://bluegriffon.org/pages/Download).
2. Right click on the Installer file. Pick the "Permissions" tab and
   check the `Allow executing file as program` checkbox. (For security
   reasons, most files aren't executable by default.)
3. Double-click on the installer file, and the GUI to install BlueGriffon will start.

About Bluegriffon, from its website:

> BlueGriffon is a new WYSIWYG content editor for the World Wide Web.
>   Powered by Gecko, the rendering engine of Firefox, it's a modern and
>   robust solution to edit Web pages in conformance to the latest Web
>   Standards.

**Partially reference:** https://askubuntu.com/a/136849/11932

The latest bluegriffon can also be installed from the getdeb repository, by doing the following steps:

```
wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bluegriffon
```

**Courtesy:** http://www.sourceslist.eu/software-tramite-repository/how-to-install-bluegriffon-editor-wysiwyg-on-ubuntu-12-04-from-ppa/

Answer (score 1):

**Kompozer** packages are removed from Quantal version but still you can download install the binaries or from source.

Here is the binaries/source [link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+package/kompozer)

Make sure you install the dependencies before installing the Kompozer .deb file

Other Alternative for Kompozer is [**aptana-studio**](http://www.texplod.com/aptana-studio-3-in-gnulinux-programmers-ide/) but you cannot find this package in ubuntu repository. You need to download them from [official website](http://www.aptana.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The KompoZer packages have been removed due to lack of maintenance (the packages can not be built from source with the 12.10 tool chain).

I suggest [Amaya](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/User/BinDist.html) and the NVU/KompoZer fork [Bluegriffon](http://www.getdeb.net/software/BlueGriffon).  Unfortunately, neither is in the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems old, but here is an alternative solution to install Kompozer. It worked for me:

STEP 1:

Download this:
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/102977...buntu2_all.deb

Once it downloads, click on it, should open Ubuntu software center, click install.

STEP 2:

Download from here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+package/kompozer

You'll see a list of options based on hardware. I downloaded the i386 because I have an intel processor. Which is this file:
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/102977...untu2_i386.deb

Once that is downloaded, same thing - click it, opens in software center, then install.

It will then install as any other and you should be good to go.

Ref: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12360288&postcount=13

Comment: The links provided for launchpadlibrarian.com are dead/giving 404 errors

Comment: @maggotbrain, Sorry, I copied the answer from the reference mentioned. It worked at the time!

Comment: @maggotbrain, here is another solution that works, so far:
`wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kompozer/kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kompozer/kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb`

Comment: Add that as an answer please, or edit yours.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that I just found:

> Unfortunately Kompozer isn't available from the Ubuntu 13.04
> repositories, therefore you have to install it as follows:
>
> ```
> cd ~/Downloads 
>
> wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kompozer/kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kompozer/kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
>
> sudo dpkg -i kompozer*.deb
> ```

source: http://www.howtoforge.com/the-perfect-desktop-ubuntu-13.04-raring-ringtail-p4