# Where do I look for the reason for the removal of a package from the Ubuntu repositories

Tags: package-management, repository, official-repositories

I have seen that when a new Ubuntu version is released, sometimes a particular application that I had used till the previous Ubuntu versions would have been removed from the Ubuntu repositories for the latest release.
Who can makes such decisions( a particular Launchpad team/individual,etc..), and which mailing-list(or other resource) should I look to find the exact reason for removal of the package from the latest Ubuntu release.

**e.g:** `Kompozer` has been removed from the repository for `Quantal`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most packages that are removed from Universe inherit that state from Debian. In order to find out the status of a package you can use the [Debian Package Tracking System](http://packages.qa.debian.org) (PTS) to look it up:

- http://packages.qa.debian.org/k/kompozer.html

Has the answer:

```
------------------- Reason -------------------
ROM; dead upstream
----------------------------------------------
```

This means the author(s) of the program have abandoned it.

Comment: Thanks man. That's what I wanted. I had totally forgot about the upstream in the picture.