# Firefox showing some parts of websites grey

Tags: 12.10, firefox

Firefox at my ubuntu 12.10 (64bit) desktop, started showing some parts of websites grey.

I tried creating a new profile, nothing.
Tried unistall with `sudo apt-get purge firefox` which removed firefox and some other firefox-tied apps, re-installed, still nothing.

This is how a page looks **in firefox**:
[image: firefox]

and how it looks **in chrome**:
[image: chrome]

Notice the image, it's a bit grey.
I have also installed the Old image style extension and it simply doesn't work.
What can I do?

Comment: Does it look like that forever, or just for a while? Firefox (and other apps) grey out while waiting for the app to complete something (running a plugin, etc.).

Comment: @James: Looks like that forever :/

Comment: In firefox, you might also try installing adblock plus add-on. It prevents most of those banners and third party advertising which sometimes can cause problems. [This is how that website looks to me](http://home.comcast.net/~jsavga//temp/Screenshot%20from%202013-01-05%2020%3A28%3A04.png) in Firefox 17.0.1.

Comment: @James look again carefully, man, it's not the whole firefox greyed out, only the image in the page an screenshot of bluegriffon in a askubuntu answer)

Comment: @James: I agree with elias. Please notice that the bluegriffon image into the askubuntu question is dimmed. I could post more examples if you'd like more convincing that it's the images and not firefox. If it was firefox the whole program would be lagging and it's not.. 
I also have adblock plus installed already :/ I thought that this was the culprit but after disabling it, it's still the same...

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, removed previous wrong comments. Can you give me the link to that askubuntu question? Also, can you verify what firefox version and what addons you're running?

Comment: @James: This should be it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/204681/kompozer-not-in-the-repo. Firefox version: 18, addons: Adblock Plus, Adblock Plus Pop-up Addon, Download Statusbar, Flash Video Downloader, Youtube Downloader, Global Menu Bar integration, Greasemonkey, LastPass, Old Default Image Style, Pocket, Transparent standalone images, Ubuntu Firefox Modifications, Xmarks. Notice that the "Old Default Image Style" and "Transparent standalone images" were install in an attempt to fix this problem. But no luck there..Also, tried restarting firefox with all addons disabled but still nothing.

Comment: What's the version of your Firefox? Make sure you update it to the latest.

Comment: @J.AustinRodriguez Firefox is up to date (v.23) and still nothing.