# Web Development in Ubuntu 12.04, I don't want to go back to Windows

Tags: 12.04, web-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 bkz I could never get 11.xx to work on my laptop in dual boot. Since I'm trying to get away from Windows 7 I want to install a Dreamweaver like tool for web dev (i'm web dev n00b).

I did my research and the best ones to me are [BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/) & [KompOzer](http://kompozer.net/) in terms of clean GUI, editor hints, WYSIWYG, etc.. but I can't get them to work on my ubuntu 12.04. since I'm new to linux and I know you can't just install programs through .exe 's I want to know if anyone has gotten these programs to work in 12.04??

I really don't want to go to windows/mac..Or do I have to if I want to do web dev the right way?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

This will be pretty easy.

For BlueGriffon:

1. Download the [installer](http://bluegriffon.org/pages/Download).
2. Right click on the Installer file. Pick the "Permissions" tab and
   check the `Allow executing file as program` checkbox. (For security
   reasons, most files aren't executable by default.)
3. Double-click on the installer file, and the GUI to install BlueGriffon will start.

For KompOzer:

1. Open up a terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+T`)
2. Type: `sudo apt-get install kompozer`
3. When asked if you want to continue, type `Y` and hit enter.
4. That's it.

Now if you go to the dashboard and type in the name of either program, you should see a launcher. :)

There is no "right" platform for web development. The one you choose is completely up to your own personal tastes. Any of them will provide sufficient tools to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks a ton I will definitely go and try this out later tonight, I'm currently at work... :(... this was just something I failed to accomplish over the weekend

Answer (score 2):

Try [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download)

I suppose there is a tar or zip archive which you can easy extract into your home folder and run this program.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to add aptana as well. Do you have a preference for the eclipse or standalone version of it? I will try to install it and compare it to kompozer/bluegriffon

Comment: Eclipse is a pretty useful IDE to use, a lot of toolkits have Eclipse plugins. There are (arguably) better IDEs out there, but Eclipse is so widely adopted that it is easy to find support for, and that is pretty handy. It's also in the official repos, so you can install it through the Ubuntu Software app.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what exactly your needs are you might also want to try [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), which is a pretty solid, lightweight and fast editor focussed on coding. It's quite extendible to suit your needs (not sure about WYSIWYG though, as far as I know that's not (yet) possible). Plus it's more lightweight than Aptana!

You don't have to install it, extracting it into any directory you like and executing it is fine. 
**Careful**: This is not freeware, and still in beta; they do, however, give you an unrestricted trial-period. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You can try "Bluefish", It is in the Ubuntu repository,

run this in the terminal -> `sudo apt-get install bluefish bluefish-plugins`.

I hope you will like this IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Geany is my favorite, fast and light.

To install it in the Software Center:
[image: Install via the software center]