# Is there anything free on ubuntu that is similar to Dreamweaver?

Tags: websites, design, web-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)

I would like to build a website.......I need something that has more or less pre-built designs (buttons, menu structures...etc) and would work on Ubuntu (under the free license thingy).

I really dont want to use e107, nor wordpress. I need something more professional looking like Dreamweaver.

I already have the domain, the ftp access....I have the photos and the text that I need on the website......so.....I need something to make the texts and the photos look good and upload them. Simple as that. Wordpress, for example, doesn't really give me this freedom. It has the prebuilt themes that are many many times hard to shift around. I need something more like dreamweaver. I dont mind the learning curve as long as it's worth spending time learning a new software.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual culprits that get a mention:

- [Quanta Plus](http://www.osalt.com/quanta)
- [Aptana](http://www.osalt.com/aptana)
- [Bluefish](http://www.osalt.com/bluefish)
- Mozilla [SeaMonkey](http://www.osalt.com/seamonkey)
- [Amaya](http://www.osalt.com/amaya)
- [Nvu](http://www.osalt.com/nvu)
- [KompoZer](http://www.osalt.com/kompozer)

Try them all?

Answer (score 0):

I've used BlueGriffon before now:

http://bluegriffon.org/