# Dreamweaver-like HTML editor for Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, editor, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)

I'm trying out Ubuntu 12.04 after a long run with OS X, and was wondering if there was an HTML (and CSS and PHP) editor with roughly the same amount of control as Adobe Dreamweaver.

Comment: @UriHerrera Objection: that question is over a year old; there might be newer software available.

Comment: The question might be old, yet the software recommended in there is the best known and has been updated since then.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll close the question. Or, well, flag it.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use Kompozer. It's fairly capable but unstable, and it has not been updated since 2010.

http://kompozer.net/

In the end I just started maintaining basic templates and doing everything by hand in a text editor.

Comment: Indeed, I recommended Kompozer to my father who is relatively non-technical.  Sad to see it's not been updated recently, but 2010 is still a lot newer than the ancient copy of Microsoft Frontpage he *was* using...

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend aptana studio if you want something similar to the web app IDE of Dreamweaver.   You will be pleased.  http://www.aptana.com/