# How do I install Quanta Plus?

Tags: kde, ide, web-development

I want to install the Quanta Plus, a web development IDE. When I try to configure the file using `./configure` then this will display:

```
subhajit@Reaper:~/Downloads/kdewebdev-3.5.8$ ./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for -p flag to install... yes
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for kde-config... not found
configure: error: The important program kde-config was not found!
Please check whether you installed KDE correctly.
```

I find some stuff like

```
sudo apt-get install kdelibs5-dev
```

and

```
sudo apt-get build-dep kstars
```

but this is not working.

If there is another way to install the Quanta Plus? Then please tell me how to install.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 32bit.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What is the reason for to not use the Ubuntu package and compile a *very old* 3.5 version from source? Package name: [kdewebdev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/kdewebdev) - just do `sudo apt-get install kdewebdev`. I believe the Quanta Plus is a very old name for one of the apps in the now KDE web development suite.

Comment: Thank You Very Much. Can You Please Tell Me How To Start This kdewebdev

Comment: Maybe my answer isn't really clear, but it's not fit for KDE4, so not fit for Ubuntu. You'll not be able to run it. Look for alternatives.

Comment: http://www.binarytides.com/install-quanta-plus-ubuntu-12-10/

Answer (score 3):

#### Forget about Quanta Plus, start looking for alternatives

The last release of Quanta Plus was about 5 years ago: version 3.5.9 ([see all versions](http://quickgit.kde.org/?p=quanta.git&a=tags)). [They are working on a port to KDE 4.](http://techbase.kde.org/Projects/Quanta/Feature_Plan_4) This port seems also a bit dead, as I see only a few commits over the last year and no tags besides the `4.2    - tag version that might work with kdev 4.2` which does not sound very much stable.

Because the whole stable source still needs Qt3 and KDE3, you won't be able to compile it anyway without huge efforts.

The `kdewebdev` package now contains some other useful tools, though:

- kfilereplace
- kimagemapeditor
- klinkstatus
- kommander

---

For alternatives to Quanta Plus see: [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)

Comment: Thank you a lot!
I found everything without kommander. Can you tell me how to open kommander?

Comment: @Reaper `kommander --help` It's not something you really want to run as a desktop application.

Comment: Can you please tell me a good web development tool for Ubuntu without kompozer, Bluefish, netbeans. Like Dreamweaver.

Comment: @Reaper Look for the **many** questions already out there on this site! Tip: use the search with the tags `software-recommendation`, `web-development` and `ide`.

Comment: @Reaper If my answer was helpful, then you may want to mark it as [accepted](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask). That is how this site works (see [about](http://askubuntu.com/about)). [Upvoting](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/vote-up), which you can do once you've gained more reputation points, is the way of saying "thank you" here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 12.04 LTS and was succesfull using this way to install QUANTA+:

**[Update]** Since Natty is not longer supported, I tried successful to use the Lucid-repositories ;) I think it's possible to install Quanta on this way up to the end-of-lifetime of lucid.... **[/Update]**

First you have to add the packages of LUCID to your sources list.

Open an editor of your choose with the soucres.list, I do it in this case with gedit.

```
# sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and insert the following lines to end of the file

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid main universe restricted multiverse

deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid universe main multiverse restricted

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security universe main multiverse restricted

deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security universe main multiverse restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates universe main multiverse restricted

deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-updates universe main multiverse restricted

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner

deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
```

Now save the file and exit gedit

Update your package-sources:

```
# sudo apt-get update
```

Install QUANTA

```
# sudo apt-get install quanta
```

Install missing apps (e.g. kommander), the KDE4-versions are working with QUANTA, only cervesia can't be used.

Have fun ;)