# Looking for a Web Development IDE with built-in FTP functionality

Tags: ftp, ide, web-development

Coming from using Espresso (not the drink, haha) on a Mac, I'm looking for a Web Development IDE that provides a built in ftp upload/download ability.

The reason being, every seperate ftp client (FileZilla, etc.) I've tried doesn't work correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers to this question: [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)  contains several programming IDE's that may fit your needs but I think that this alternative may be the best for your case: https://askubuntu.com/a/59636/9598. It won't be reproduced right here.

For the case that you need support connecting to the FTP server for upload/download/sync, please refer to the accepted answer on this question on StackOverflow: [How Connect to remote host from Aptana Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201939/how-connect-to-remote-host-from-aptana-studio-3) which I place here for your convenience:

> From the Project Explorer, expand the project you want to hook up to a
>   remote site (or just right click and create a new Web project that's
>   empty if you just want to explore a remote site from there). There's a
>   "Connections" node, right click it and select "Add New connection...".
>   A dialog will appear, at bottom you can select the destination as
>   Remote and then click the "New..." button. There you can set up an
>   FTP/FTPS/SFTP connection.
>
> That's how you set up a connection that's tied to a project, typically
>   for upload/download/sync between it and a project.
>
> You can also do Window > Show View > Remote. From that view, you can
>   click the globe icon in the upper right to add connections and in this
>   view you can just browse your remote connections.

Additionally, for your needs on a stable/reliable FTP Client I suggest you gFTP, which does a great work to upload/download. A Screenshot is placed here for you to see gFPT in action:

[image]

If you need further support don't hesitate to drop a comment.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bluefish. You can connect to a server and edit files with many utilities.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans is really robust and fast. It has great FTP/SFTP support. It is also free. 
https://netbeans.org