# Is it possible to run Adobe Dreamweaver on Ubuntu?

Tags: adobe

Is there any way you can run Adobe Dreamweaver, or other similar Adobe products such as Photoshop, on Ubuntu?

Comment: For Ubuntu alternatives: [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](http://askubuntu.com/q/59632/176889)

Comment: I recommend Brackets and Google Chrome, it's kinda new and really awesome for html/css/js development !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the reviews of [Adobe Dreamweaver](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=183) and [Photoshop](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=17) at the [WineHQ App Database](https://appdb.winehq.org/), both applications can be run on Ubuntu using Wine, which is available from the default Ubuntu repositories Different versions of Dreamweaver and Photoshop have been given ratings ranging from Bronze to Platinum.

Comment: To run it using Wine, therefore, you would need to install Wine from the Ubuntu Software Centre and read the details in the links for anything specific you might need to do after that. Then you can right-click on the Dreamweaver install application and click `Open with Wine Windows Program Loader`.

Alternatively, you can install PlayOnLinux from the Ubuntu Software Centre and then click `Install` and search for Dreamweaver, click the program, click `Install in the bottom-right of the window and follow the on-screen instructions. PlayOnLinux uses Wine but automates some of the trickier stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Try installing them under Wine. [The Wine app database](http://appdb.winehq.org/) claims that [Dreamwaver CS6 needs workarounds to be installed](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26222) and that [Photoshop CS6 works with some problems](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25607).

Older versions might work better.