# What are the alternatives to Notepad++ on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor

I use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) on Windows 7 and I want to know if there is a good substitution for it on Ubuntu.

I want something that is good for editing html files.

Comment: There is GEdit (default editor for Gnome) and Kate (default one for KDE). These are very user friendly, I don't know if they are "html friendly" enough, though. Nonetheless, there are many alternatives (*Linux is full of choice*) which are targeted specifically towards web development (google `ubuntu html editors`). You can also use Oracle's Eclipse (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868/what-is-the-best-html-editor-for-eclipse)).

Comment: gedit works fine for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)

Comment: Thanks a lot, for those who wants to know how to install **"Sublime"** you can easly follow the different steps explain here: [how2 INstall Sublime](http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/) c u

Comment: For all still searching, see http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20446/tabbed-text-editor-that-autosaves-even-new-files The question addresses the lack of an editor which auto-saves and auto-loads all opened tabs on startup, even without having saved their content into a file.

Comment: gedit is much more inferior to Notepad++. I can say after years using both and still can't find a near equivalent, even after installing lots of plugins into gedit. Notepad++ has tons of features builtin and is almost like an IDE whereas gedit is purely a text editor with limited support for programming

Comment: I like [Notepadqq](https://notepadqq.com/wp/), "a Notepad++-like editor for the Linux desktop.".

Answer (score 79):

Actually you can install Notepad++ by installing [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) first:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install wine
```

But some good alternatives are:

1. [Vim](http://www.vim.org)
2. [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)
3. [Geany](http://www.geany.org/)
4. [kate](http://kate-editor.org/) (in KDE, running in unity with the installation of the proper
   KDE dependences)
5. [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (free, unlimited trial version/ or $70.00 US Dollars)
6. [GEdit](https://projects.gnome.org/gedit/)
7. [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit/downloads) (in KDE)
8. [Editra](http://editra.org)

Of these, Geany and GEdit are my favorites, but it depends on your needs. If you are looking for something more complex, there is the Aptana Studio which I mentioned in detail as an answer in this question: **[Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/a/59636/9598)**

Good luck!

Comment: Sublime has a free, unlimited trial version.

Comment: Yeah. Sublime is by far my favorite. The popups can be a bit annoying if your using the trial, but you don't lose anything for doing it.

Comment: Sublime gets my vote, also. It's too bad that there's no notepad++ for Linux (or OS X). Sublime is worth every of the 70 dollars.

Comment: Geany is at least having the same editor widget as Notepad++ is having ;)

Comment: My vote goes for emacs. Since it is fully scriptable (Lisp) there exist extensions for nearly everything you can think of. Only drawback: You have to learn some of the keyboard shortcuts, otherwise emacs will drive you crazy.

Comment: A note on this: Notepad++ has issues and hangs while using its live edit NppFTP plugin while running under Wine, at least as of March 2016. Trying to change servers will exhibit this behavior. This, IMO, is the best feature of Npp. Just a minor annoyance to remember before you try to connect to a new server with unsaved work. Sessions may save the work, but there is a chance it will nuke it too.

Comment: `vim` is not an alternative to Notepad++. Its shortcut keys are nothing short of [atrocious](https://twitter.com/iamdevloper/status/435555976687923200?lang=en).

Comment: The question specifically set "good for editing html files". For such purpose even nano is great. And  ... Is vim difficult for you? Just have a read to the handbook before you start your rocket's engine, man!

Comment: Alt key for block mode conflicts with ubuntu Alt key use.  (So no block mode).

Comment: the Wine solution works very well. After long time usage, here are the only (!) drawbacks I experienced: 1. Startup time first time 5-10 sec, after that 2-3 sec. 2. ctrl a in search window not working. 3. menu bar needs to stay, shortcuts `alt` or `f11`dont work. 4. handling huge files is significantly slower, but still very much enough for <10MB. 5. cant be seemlessly integrated into ubuntu gui. for example, for using as default you need to specify a path to "/home/[user]/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe", and I dont think you can put it in your list of standard appli

Comment: From all of your given programs, only sublme supports Notepad++'s feature of re-opening the last session on startup, without having to save any open files.

Comment: Wine will cost you three quarters of a gig of space.

Answer (score 75):

Thanks to the work of [Daniel Di Sardi](https://github.com/danieleds) there is an editor inspired to Notepad++ for Linux:

[Notepadqq](https://notepadqq.com/s/) is a Notepad++-like editor for the Linux desktop.

**Notice** that the start of the GitHub page says, since May 27, 2023:

> This project is not actively maintained anymore. New maintainers are welcome.
>
> -- Daniele

[image: notepadqq screenshot on linux]

As another option, [SciTe](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) is based on the same "[editing building block" of Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/).

Comment: looks pretty good. missing feature: auto-saving and thus, auto-loading the (unsaved) files from last session (pretty new feature in n++, yet extremely useful)

Comment: Ok, It's pretty good, but it's still lacking many features that Notepad++ has.

Comment: In particular, there is no ability to Print in the version I have: 0.51.0

Comment: It's not an exact port (The autosave feature mentioned in other comments is REALLY awesome in N++), but it has language support and will work for most of my uses. +1, thanks a lot.

Comment: Notepadqq lacks macro support, at least as of a year ago. The screen shots seem to show macro support, but it's not there in the current version.

Comment: Notepadqq is extremely fast in loading files (huge) similar like Notepad++,  recommended alternate

Comment: Notepadqq is **not** a port. From the website: *"This project is independent from Notepad++ **and doesn’t use any of its code.** Notepadqq is inspired by Notepad++: this means that we try to reproduce its best traits, while not being afraid to make different choices on what we think can be improved."*

Comment: @android-dev fixed. Although that phrase was copied from the website when I first answered... So something changed. Good... Thanks for the head-up.

Answer (score 35):

It is actually possible to install Notepad++ on Ubuntu. Just run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Then, download the Notepad++ Windows installer, right click it, and select Open With -> Wine Windows Program Loader. Follow the typical installation process and you should be able to open Notepad++ from your Dash.

Comment: Really this is good solution you can know more about wine http://www.winehq.org/about/

Comment: this works so well, so easily - I wish I'd have know how easy it was years ago !

Comment: Can't get column mode working due to Alt key conflict.  Workaround anyone?

Comment: @Elipticalview ALT+SHIFT

Comment: I had success with Notepad++ version 7.3.3, 32bit on Wine on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but no success with the latest Notepad++ version 7.5.4.

Answer (score 9):

Nowadays I would recommend [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). It's free, open-source and runs everywhere!

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) says:

> Visual Studio Code is a source code editor developed by Microsoft for Windows, Linux and macOS. It includes support for debugging, embedded Git control, syntax highlighting, intelligent code completion, snippets, and code refactoring. It is also customizable, so users can change the editor's theme, keyboard shortcuts, and preferences. It is free and open-source, although the official download is under a proprietary license.
>
> Visual Studio Code is based on Electron, a framework which is used to deploy Node.js applications for the desktop running on the Blink layout engine. Although it uses the Electron framework, the software is not a fork of Atom, it is actually based on Visual Studio Online's editor (codename "Monaco").

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend [Atom](https://atom.io/). Advantages:

- multi-platform (works also on Windows, MacOS),
- developed and backed by GitHub,
- based on standard technologies like Chromium web browser and JavaScript,
- and therefore has huge base of extensions for many use cases.

Comment: you did not mention that it is more resource hungry than other text editors

Comment: It's a good editor, but not perfect. What about the disadvantages? Stock Atom is slow and uses way too many resources. Installing the FB packages will also use 100% of your disk throughput and install far too many GBs of data. Eventually you may not even be able to start the app. Perhaps FB have fixed this by now, but i doubt it (considering the millions of lines of code and sheer package size).

Comment: @dhaupin, You are right, Atom also has some disadvantages.  BTW, what do you mean when you talk about "FB" packages?

Comment: @RobertZelník oo my bad, FB = Facebook. Their suite is http://nuclide.io. Its pretty sweet, but incredibly heavy. I cant wait till some of these atom packages "slim down" if that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your explanation. As I understand, Nuclide.io is a package for Atom developed by FB team, independently on Atom itself, so there's no reason to anyhow review Nuclide when we talk about Atom. However, you are right about resource-hunger of Atom and web-browser-based applications in general. Thank you for your notice, I will try to rewrite my recommendation.

Answer (score 7):

**Other alternatives** which have rich features including easy-to-use **macro** tools:

## KKEdit

☞ **http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/kkedit-text-editor-inspired-by-bbedit.html**

☞ **https://github.com/KeithDHedger/KKEdit**

☞ **http://linux-apps.com/content/show.php/KKEdit?content=158161**

- The usual source view options, split-view, line wrap, line numbers etc.
- Full source code highlighted printing.
- Standard text search OR regex search in current or all open files.
- Jump to function declaration, Find Function declaration.
- Find API declarations in installed Gtk-Doc's.
- Find and open include file.
- Multiple bookmarks.
- Run external tools.
- Save/Restore session.
- Run external tool synchronously or asynchronously.
- Pass selected text to external tools.
- Spell checking via ASpell, check selected word or check document via tab menu.

[image]

## medit [image: Install medit]

[Official site](http://mooedit.sourceforge.net/)

- Configurable syntax highlighting.
- Configurable keyboard accelerators.
- Multiplatform - works on unix and windows.
- Plugins: can be written in C, Python, or Lua.
- Configurable tools available from the main and context menus. They can be written in - Python or Lua, or it can be a shell script.
- Regular expression search/replace, grep frontend, builtin file selector, etc.

  [image: medit screenshot]

Comment: medit is in the default Ubuntu package repository, is very snappy to load, has a GUI, and is as text-focused as notepad++ (compared to a lot of IDEs in other answers). It's an excellent option. The only thing I miss so far is how notepad++ facilitates "scrap paper" by storing unsaved, untitled notes somewhere temporary behind the scenes, on close.

Answer (score 6):

Three other alternatives:

1. Gedit
2. Bluefish (Ubuntu Software Center)
3. [Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download)

**Bluefish** is very good for HTML and CSS in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try Atom? https://atom.io/

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install atom
```

Or, did you try Sublime Text??
http://www.sublimetext.com/

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Sublime is not free and sometimes when using it displays a notification to buy it. But, you can "evaluate it" as much as you want. (Sublime website says "There is currently no enforced time limit for the evaluation" )

Comment: It would help to mention the major caveat that Sublime costs $70 and will deploy pop-ups and whatnot if the user hasn't paid.

Answer (score 3):

I've not been able to get notepad++ to work with wine/ubuntu. Nevertheless, you can install notepadd++ as a snap and it works just fine.

Go to https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy and follow the links. Snaps are available for a variety of containerized software packages. The snap "store" is located at https://snapcraft.io/store. The homepage is https://snapcraft.io .

Or check out https://linuxconfig.org/a-beginner-s-introduction-to-snaps-the-universal-linux-package-format or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_(package_manager).

Answer (score 3):

## Ubuntu 14.04 and later

Notepad++ (*notepad-plus-plus*) is a snap package in the default repositories of all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install Notepad++ open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus
```

To add Notepad++ navigation to other drives besides the default drive:

```
sudo snap connect notepad-plus-plus:removable-media
```

[image]
<sup>Even though the window title says [Administrator] this file is opened with normal user permissions in Notepad++.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Try [eric4](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/eric-download.html).

I use both notepadd++ on windows and eric4 on Debian. Eric is superior in many ways to notepad++ in my opinion and is free.

Comment: As I, for one, can't read your mind, please enumerate some of those "many ways".

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [scribes](http://scribes.sourceforge.net/). Features:

- Automatic word completion
- Automatic correction and replacement
- Automatic pair character completion and smart insertion
- Automatic indentation
- Many languages

Answer (score 2):

[Brackets](http://brackets.io/) is a modern, open source text editor that understands web design. It's crafted from the ground up for web designers and front-end developers.

It is available for many OSs and works pretty good with Ubuntu. To install Brackets in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install --classic brackets
```

[image]