# What editor provides highlighted and clickable hyperlinks? (similar to Notepad++)

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor, url

I have about a 1000 links in my txt file and I don't want to copy paste them in my browser.

So I am looking for a text editor that highlights URLs and makes them clickable.Please note that I am looking for a text editor (like kate, sublime) and not a full IDE.

I have tried Sublime, Kate, gedit etc, but I can't figure how to highlight URLs and hyperlinks there

Comment: @AvinashRaj OmG! I said that I tried sublime, there is no highlighting

Comment: @EliahKagan I don't think this is a duplicate. OP isn't asking for a full Notepad replacement, they are asking how to replicate one specific feature in a text editor supporting Ubuntu.

Comment: @Glutanimate You are right. While [What are the alternatives to Notepad++ on Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/313973/22949) is relevant to this question, this question is specifically asking for editors that present hyperlinks in a particular way to the user. I have removed my close vote.

Comment: I use Zim. I just added my old text files to Zim it it created directly click-able links. Only issue I have is with copy & paste into forums, it seems to have hidden formating or line ending and added extra blank lines.

Comment: BTW, what are those links? Link to files (like pdf, jpg, png, exe, deb, zip, etc) that you want to download? In such a case, you can simply use `wget` to download all the links by providing it the `--input-file` or `-i` option; like `wget -i /path/to/file/containing/links`.

Answer (score 3):

It's too simple, just Open Terminal by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
    cat -n /File_Path/File_Name
```

With `-n` option you could see the line numbers of a file "File_Name" in the output terminal for easy to understand which line you clicked last time.

If file having large number of contains (like yours) that won't fit in output terminal and screen scrolls up very fast, we can use parameters `more` or `less` with `cat` command as show below.

```
    cat -n /File_Path/File_Name | less
```

or

```
    cat -n /File_Path/File_Name | more
```

Then you need to hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key down while left clicking to open links in a browser, or right click and select the context menu option "Open Link". enjoy

Comment: Or `less YOUR_TEXT_FILE` for easy paging with the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs's org-mode the URLs are highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

[There's a Sublime plugin for this](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/ClickableUrls_SublimeText). From the Github description:

> [image]
>
> This plugin underlines URLs in Sublime Text, and lets you open them with a keystroke (Cmd+Option+Enter by default).
>
> After you put the cursor over an URL, you can either hit Cmd+Option+Enter (Ctrl+Alt+Enter on Windows & Linux), or select "Open URL under cursor" from the Command Palette. Instead of selecting an auto detected URL, you can select any block of text and it will also open in a browser as a URL.

However, this plugin might not be the right choice for thousands of URLs:

> **Performance warning**. The plugin is automatically disabled if the document has more than 200 URLs, in order to avoid a massive performance hit.

As with most Sublime plugins you can install `Clickable URLs` via [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control).

Answer (score 0):

Now Notepad++ (with ability to click by links) can be installed on Ubuntu from snap.

```
    sudo apt install snapd snapd-xdg-open
    sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus
```

[How to Install Notepad++ Editor on Ubuntu](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-notepad-on-ubuntu/)

However Notepad++ does not have official support for Linux (and Ubuntu).
And there is problem with copy-pasting from Notepad++ to Terminal. But workaround is very simple. To past from Notepad++ to Terminal, <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> shortcut can be used instead of <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.

> Moved back from Linux to Windows ~12 months ago, hope that memory
> serves. There could be multiple issues.
>
> If you are talking about problems of copy-pasting between Notepad++
> and terminal (or other Linux app) then you are likely facing the
> problem of Linux PRIMARY and SECONDARY paste buffers. Go read about
> it. Notepad++ over wine is copying into SECONDARY buffer and to paste
> into terminal you need special shortcut: ctrl-shift-v. For the other
> way around copy with ctrl-ins from terminal and paste with ctrl-v into
> Notepad++.
>
> From your description, I assume you are copy-pasting from Notepad++
> into Notepad++. Don’t remember an issue like you described. I could
> guess that ctrl-ins and shift-ins are global shortcuts in the Linux
> system. This may lead into race where 2 entities, Notepad++ and
> “Linux”, manipulate the clipboard (or paste buffers) which leads to
> unpredictable results. Using ctrl-c and ctrl-v should workaround THAT
> issue since they are far less global. If that is indeed the problem
> then disabling global effects of ctrl-ins shift-ins will be VERY
> difficult. These shortcuts are embedded deep into the system.
>
> There are also helper applications that should do automatic
> synchronization between PRIMARY and SECONDARY buffers to help. I
> didn’t install any of them myself. But as many kinds of “help” they
> may leave you off worse than you started.

[Ubuntu, copy paste, works half the time](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/20545/ubuntu-copy-paste-works-half-the-time)

I tested this on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

URLs are recognized and automatically italicized, underlined and  Ctrl-left clickable in Featherpad.  example; *https://www.bbc.com/weather/2759794*

Answer (score -1):

What about [Featherpad](https://github.com/tsujan/FeatherPad)?

> FeatherPad (by Pedram Pourang [...]) is a lightweight Qt plain-text editor for Linux. It is independent of any desktop environment

The list of features includes

> - Ability to open URLs with appropriate applications