# What is the best editor for HTML, CSS etc?

Tags: programming, html, editor, css

in Windows I'm using Komodo & Notepad++ for coding HTML, CSS etc. In Ubuntu, what's the best editor I can use? Thanks :)

Comment: This question is an opinion. I suggest gedit or vim. YMMV

Comment: Note these questions are often seen as too broad and opnion based for this site, as they are many different answer and you will get only opinions of what people prefer best. . Also try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/313973/what-are-the-alternatives-to-notepad-on-ubuntu

Comment: @muru - no, DreamWeaver is more a WYSIWYG HTML editor that has a nice habit of butchering code and producing things for IE only :). You would need [bluegriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/) not bluefish then.

Comment: @Wilf Don't care. Answers fit the question. Either that or close as opinion based.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My personal favorite for web programming would have to be [Brackets](http://www.brackets.io).

[image]

It has support and syntax highlighting for many, many languages, and has plenty of awesome features.

It has an awesome interface that's really easy to use, along with a whole raft of features, like over 100 extensions accessible right from within a built-in Extension Manager, live-preview which allows you to see the changes you make right away – no reloading the page any more, quick-edit that allows you to edit the CSS for the current tag without changing files, tag completion, and a bunch more.

Granted, you have to have Chrome (or Chromium, that works too) to use the Live Preview, but that is probably one of the best features. Basically, you can tweak a bit of code within the page's code and you can see that change as soon as you complete the code line.

Here’s [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvo3Mv1Z4qU), albeit a bit outdated, that provides a basic introduction to Brackets and its features.

You can add a PPA to install Brackets get automatic updates for it via:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brackets
```

Comment: Well done! I installed it and it seems to work great! Thank you! I also like Sublime Text 3 :)

Comment: @MeymiGrøuMey That's also another very god one. When I wrote this I actually hadn't discovered Sublime Text yet, but have since. Still, I prefer Brackets for web programming since that's its main focus. ST3 is very good though, and it's what I use for all my application programming.

Answer (score 10):

Bluefish is great - it supports HTML, CSS, JS and much more besides. Also supports tag completion , multi-threading & documenting etc. You can install it from the repos using:

```
sudo apt-get install bluefish
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Note you can install Notepad++ under [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/about/), and a [script](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-69-Notepad.html) for [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com) is also available

Comment: Good thing about Bluefish, it [supports gvfs](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/manual/ch05s12.html) making it possible to easily edit files on remote servers (I use `sftp://user@server` but [other schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVfs) are supported)

Comment: I'm turned off by the fact this is just another extendable text editor, but the more screenshots I see of this, the more comparable it looks to a fully featured IDE... This looks extremely useful! :D

Comment: except for the fact it seems to freeze on large generated HTML documents.

Comment: @Tcll - which version are you using?

Comment: should be the latest I think... I'm using this on Xubuntu 14.04... * checks * nope... 2.2.5 :O

Answer (score 4):

Gedit is a pretty nice tool, its like the notepad of Linux. There are more specialized programs out there but sometimes the simplest work the best :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, have you tried Sublime Text 3 or Brackets? If not, you should check them out :)

Comment: Exactly correct.