# Apps running with wine looking ugly

Tags: wine, kubuntu, themes, kde, plasma-5

I've installed notepad++ with wine. If I run this application it looks like Win95.

So now twenty years have past and I would appreciate a look that is a tiny bit more state of the art.

I found this solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/219795/249909

Applying the accepted answer results in nicely looking winecfg. But notepad++ still looks ugly as before.

Not only that: Using the theme causes that the toolbar of notepad++ is not longer visible:

[image]

So, instead one step forward this was one step back.
How to solve this?

Comment: This looks like a problem of Wine integration with the DE, rather than Ubuntu itself.

Comment: You can try a different theme (e.g. there are [loads on deviantart](http://www.deviantart.com/browse/all/?section=&global=1&q=msstyles) - like the [UbuntuLight theme](http://aerilius.deviantart.com/art/Ubuntu-Light-Themes-12-10-327631977)) Which desktop environment are you using?

Comment: I tried a few. Everytime the same. I've tried it with Plasma 5.2 and 5.3...

Comment: isn't that releated to the windows version wine is using (usually xp)

Comment: Have you tried the native port of Notepad++? See http://askubuntu.com/a/413179/16395