# Notepad++ not working after removing wine that was installed for a different application

Tags: apt, wine, snap

I had notepad++ for a while now, installed directly from Ubuntu software center. AFAI remember I didn't have to specifically install wine.

Yesterday I wanted to install a different *.exe and had to install wine (otherwise it wouldn't run). It wreaked havoc on my system, and I found online that wine might be the issue (which it was). I uninstalled with `sudo apt-get --purge remove wine`, and now I can't open notepad++ (not surprised). But I had open files there that are not saved (notepad++ has some sort of cache where it stores all the non saved files). Is there a possibility to reinstall wine and reconnect it back with the Notepad++ installation?

Tried to follow this, but didn't help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923102/notepad-plus-plus-snap-does-not-start-on-ubuntu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the alternatives to Notepad++ on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313973/what-are-the-alternatives-to-notepad-on-ubuntu) Notepad++ is a native snap package in Ubuntu that can be installed from Ubuntu Software or from the terminal with `sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus && sudo snap connect notepad-plus-plus:removable-media` as answered in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1050174/).

Comment: Answering my own question - the main reason I couldn't reinstall it is the files that are open in notepad++. I found them: `[HOME_DIRECTORY]/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine/drive_c/users/[MY_USER_NAME]/Application Data/Notepad++/backup`. Now I can reinstall notepad++ and hopefully it'll work. Thanks

Comment: Most Ubuntu user prefer to install software with the Ubuntu software app. Apps installed by Ubuntu Software are updated automatically. Why do you shun the Ubuntu Software app?

Comment: Might I recommend [notepadqq](https://notepadqq.com)? I suspect you'll like it if you like notepad++. It'll avoid all that fussing about with wine.