# Text editor like Adobe Dreamweaver for Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor, ide

I'm new to this Ubuntu 13.04, and I'm a web designer and developer I used Dreamweaver when I am using windows so can any one help me which of the text editor is best to use which helps me in designing (HTML, CSS, jQuery, JavaScript) and developing (PHP, MySql) and which is same like adobe Dreamweaver and can you also help me how to install it in my Ubuntu 13.04 64bit.

Comment: Try brackets http://brackets.io/

Comment: Can you add that as an answer? @dedunumax

Comment: but how to install Brackets in ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also Web-Developer. In my opinion, Dreamweaver is an expensive and unnecessary ballony for a developer who works in HTML, CSS, jQuery, JavaScript, php/mysql, java and so on.

I use NETBEANS for developement. It's the real dream. It runs to my knowledge on all linux distributions.

For art design and photography I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Gimp 2.8, RAWThereapie, Phatch, scribus.... Only OpenSource! It's more than enough for development, publishing and design.

Answer (score 2):

Use Brackets

http://brackets.io/

Please go to this link and download deb file. http://download.brackets.io/

Then go to the folder that you download deb file, using `cd` command.

`dpkg -i brackets-sprint-30-LINUX64.deb`

(You may have to change brackets-sprint-30-LINUX64.deb part according to the file you download.)

Under Programming category you can find Brackets. This was developed by Adobe as I know

Comment: I started to use and for me, is the best choice until now. There cool plugins for Brackets :). Thanks, dedunumax!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Dreamweaver, but as a web developer I use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/). It has a lot of nice little features like multi select, split editing and addons that makes the small annoying things easier.

To install, run the following in the terminal (gotten from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/227617/164891))

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Answer (score 0):

The most nearest thing I know to dreamweaver is http://www.kompozer.net. Other than that http://bluegriffon.org/ might be useful as well.

Both are installable through http://www.getdeb.net

But as a developer I would recommend you to use other available options, I think http://www.aptana.com/ may be better choice for you.

If you are fan of minimalism, I would recommend `geany`.

See [What IDEs are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu) for available IDE.

Also see [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)

Answer (score 0):

Try KompoZer.  KompoZer is a complete web authoring system that combines web file management and easy-to-use WYSIWYG web page editing.

KompoZer is designed to be extremely easy to use, making it ideal for non-technical computer users who want to create an attractive, professional-looking web site without needing to know HTML or web coding.<sup>[Kompozer](http://kompozer.net/)</sup>

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo sudo add-apt-repository ppa:giuseppe-iuculano/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kompozer
```

Another option is

Amaya is a Web editor, i.e. a tool used to create and update documents directly on the Web. Browsing features are seamlessly integrated with the editing and remote access features in a uniform environment. This follows the original vision of the Web as a space for collaboration and not just a one-way publishing medium.<sup>[Amaya](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/)</sup>

When downloading Amaya make sure that you download the right file for your architecture.

[Download](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/Distribution/amaya_11.4.7-1_i386.deb) and install Amaya.  Once downloaded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the download folder (probably the Downloads folder), and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <file_name>.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

vim works great for me

This will get you started with a nice config

https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim

I find big heavy programs crash a lot.  I personally love how light weight vim is and easily can do anything dreamweaver can, or netbeans.

Then you add in git and you are in a good position.