# How to create an android html app easily?

Tags: android, html

What is the easiest way to create an android html app ? In windows  I can create it by using dreamweaver and phonegap . How about ubuntu 13.10 64bit ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use phonegap with any editor you like, Sublime-text, Brackets, Eclipse etc.

For a more gui like design tool take a look at http://xdk-software.intel.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can -indeed- code your own HTML/HTML5 app using any of the software recommendations mentioned in the answers to this question: [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)

Of which I suggest you the usage of Aptana Studio 3 (The accepted answer so far). After which you can deploy your application by using an app generator website like **[AppsGeyser](http://www.appsgeyser.com/)** which will allow you to distribute both online content applications and standalone compressed applications.

There are some other App Generator Websites, and the majority of them uses a custom web browser that gains access to either your online/standalone web content with ease creating the illusion of having a "native app" for both Android and iOS devices.

For PHP based applications you will be in the need to host your web content somewhere in a server and make it accessible on the net in order to allow the custom browser "app" to gain access and reproduce the right server/user-side responses.

Please let us know if this makes some sense to what you wish or not in order to provide you with the proper support as needed.

Good luck!