# A/B testing software

Tags: software-recommendation, testing, web-development, optimization

I am looking for A/B testing and optimization software for web-page development in ubuntu. Can I get some software recommendations?

Comment: maybe this be some useful http://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver

Comment: Those softwares arent bad for general web development, but I would like to test performance of pages simultaneously for things like load time. I can maybe hack up a solution if i need to using firfox plugins, and some scripting, but I can also see difficulties in trying to write something like A\B testing software from scratch. If bluefish, or aptana studio have this feature I am unaware where they are.

Comment: in that comment that I posted if you roll down to the bottom there's a software called `Brackets` it has preview feature and others, check that for a purpose.

Comment: ok Ill look into it.