# How can i install Dreamweaver CS6 in UBuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10

I need one help.I need to install Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 only on my Ubuntu 15.01 machine. Can anybody please provide me the steps to install with the proper key.I have installed cs6 with patch .dll file in my windows machine so similarly how can i do this in Ubuntu. PLease help me the required steps.

Comment: No,By using .dll file i can get full version of cs6 in windows like this i want to install cs6 in ubuntu.

Comment: This says it does not run well https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26222 How about an alternative? http://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver

Comment: Is there any other solution to install or any other editior same as dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Windows software on Linux, you have to use winehq (https://www.winehq.org/) or possibly crossover (https://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover-linux) although crossover is payment.

Greetings.