# Website Editor wanted

Tags: web-development, web-design

I'm asking what might on the surface look like a repeat question but it's not because no one has actually answered the question asked.  I'm looking for the equivalent of FrontPage for Ubuntu.  FrontPage is a site and not just a page editor because it maintains links as pages graphics are moved around and even when the architecture is changed.  And, very important to a busy executive, it has an auto-thumbnail feature.

So far the advice has been

- Learn HTML and Javascript.  zero interest or time.
- Blue Gryphon - gimpware that will probably go away with Mozilla's XUL API.  I've tried it and find it a decent **page** editor but not a site editor.  Plus he's abandoned 32 bit users.
- Amaya - I think it would be a nice **Page** editor if it would run properly on my machine (12.04LTS).  As is, there is a 1 or 2 pixel line where the tool bar should be.  And it won't render anything until some toolbar action is taken.  I can work at it and hit a toolbar item with the cursor, whereup the page renders.  IT still appears to only be a page editor, though.
- Brackets - HTML editor.  Not applicable.
- Use a CMS - I have a blog on WordPress.  Over my Hughsnet link it takes approximately 15 seconds for the first page to load while WP sends out seemingly hundreds of files.  My personal site's FrontPage-created index page loads in a second.  Maybe I'm the last guy on earth who cares about load times but I do.  I realize that not everybody has or can get a gigabit connection.

So I ask again, is there a **website** editor out there for Ubuntu?  I'll even consider a commercial product.  Or do I have to continue editing with FrontPage in a VM?

Comment: Kompozer? http://askubuntu.com/a/43236/158442

Comment: I've been using Kompozer enough to get to know it.  It's a page editor and not a site editor.  Plus it has no thumbnailer.   I like to have a full size image behind every web-friendly image on my site.  Thumbnailing by hand is a real pain compared to FrontPage's right click action.

Comment: Bluefish can do thumbnails.  But it is not WYSIWYG.

Comment: Get someone else to build a site for you then.

Answer (score 0):

you could always try to run frontpage through wine, then at least you don't have to use virtual machine... maybe it will work, but cannot promise you anything. if you already have the frontpage installer you could try it very easily by right-clicking the setup file and opening it with wine program loader.. if you do not have wine you can always install it.. it is free. http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Wine-on-Ubuntu

, but remember that open-source is always nicer than proprietary. even though the website editors are a bit of a devil.

maybe also there are some online editors that can help you, try searching for that. Also php can be quite magical.. once coded = no more worries